# Why are some of my circuits not working?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

It started with the oven not getting power and than if you turn on the front element on high everything would come on but not heat to full capacity and if you turned off the element or turned it off of high everything went off. And now my washer has no power to it and all the lights and garage door will not work in the garage. They are all on they own circuit breaker and the garage has its own panel with 3 switches. Any suggestions on what may be causing this?

Comment: Are all the effected circuits on the panel in the garage or are there circuits from the main panel also exhibiting these odd work/don't work/only-work-when-something-else-is-on symptoms?

Comment: They are _all_ on their own breaker, or they're _each_ on their own? What's a "panel with 3 switches"? Is that a sub-panel of circuit breakers or a row of wall switches? Please revise to clarify.

Comment: It sounds like you might have one leg of your service down, which is a dangerous power company issue.

Comment: The washer and oven are on in the same panel and the garage has it's own panel with breakers. Washer and oven o are on their own breaker.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you lost one of the hot legs to your service. It could be a bad connection on your main breaker, a bad connection in the meter base (had this exact same thing happen at my church's parsonage...an old house with very old electrical), or a bad connection at the transformer, or the overhead (assuming you have an overhead feed) connections to the triplex from the transformer to the wires at the weather head.

Loose connections can be very confounding...when they heat up, they lose connection or provide a very poor connection. Then they cool down and make a somewhat better connection...for a while!

You should get the power company involved to at least see if there are no issues with the supply.   If not, then proceed to trace down the problem using a multi meter, starting with the main breaker.   Be careful!  You'll be dealing with REAL POWER there. PPE and rubber gloves that are certified for electrical work would make you pretty safe, but still....PPE is needed, esp. goggles.

Comment: I had the electric company come out and he said it is a bad breaker at the outside breaker box. So thank you all for your help.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for letting us know what you found.   So often, people ask a question, we give advise/answers and then don't hear how it was resolved.   Very grateful you let us  know, it helps others as well.  Wish I could give you 10 up votes for letting us know how this was solved, but I gave you what I could!

Comment: @JaymeHarris additionally, be sure to click the check mark next to this answer so that others will know it's got a resolution, too!